# the last for loop do not execute as I wish

Tags: c#

I have written some code for registration! you can give name, family name and age to this program and see what you have written then. very easy!
But when I try to print the given data, in the last for loop, only last input will come up. I am confused why. plz help. tnx  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALm0V.jpg

```
studenti.id = i;

// ask user if he wants to add more students
Console.WriteLine("do you want to add more? if no please write -No- to terminate and see what you have entered. If yes, please enter -Yes-");
string read = Console.ReadLine();

if (read == "No")
{
    for (i = 1 ; i <= studenti.id ; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id of student {0} is: " + studenti.id, i);
        Console.WriteLine("name of student {0} is: " + studenti.name, i);
        Console.WriteLine("family name of student {0} is: " + studenti.familyName, i);
        Console.WriteLine("age of student {0} is: " + studenti.age, i);

    }
```

Comment: Please post code instead of images. It´s hard to read those - and harder to copy them for the sake of reproduction of your issue.

Comment: Sorry! I have been trying to post my code for the last 15 minutes!!! but I could not.I copy and paste the code from VS here but does not let me confirm my question.

Comment: Why this? Just copy the **relevant** parts of your code, not your entire solution. No-one will scan hundreds of lines for your errors, we all have jobs to do.

Comment: You could not post your code or the image? You need some rep to let the image show, but the point is: don't use an image, post your code as text (indented by 4 spaces to mark it as code).

Comment: the code is here!

Comment: You only have a single `studenti` object, if you want more, you will need to create a `List` of them for example.

Answer (score 0):

First off you want to make sure you have a List of `Student` so you can have multiple students as follows `List<Student> students = new List<Student>();`. Then when you add a student you call `studenti.Add(<new student object>)`.

Then when you want to loop through all of them you loop through as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < studenti.Count; i++){
  Student current = studenti[i];

  //Do with each student whatever you want to
}
```

then when you want to get the last student you do `s.Last()` or `s[s.Count-1]` both return the last student added. No need for the loop in the code you posted.

Also, computers generally count from 0 when you talk about array or List indexes. So I'd suggest looping from 0 (including) to the highest number (excluding)

Comment: He needs a loop. He doesn't want the last he wants all.

Comment: he does though, the piece of code he posted is to view the last one he added and then he has a separate input for seeing all of them, which you can see in the image at the top: `Press -Add- to add students or -See- to see previous students`. Also I have code to loop through all of them in the post itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a List like: List students = new List();
Then you add your objects to the list: students.Add(someStudentobject);

And then:

```html
for (i = 0 ; i <= students.Count() ; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("id of student {0} is: " + students[i].id, i);
        Console.WriteLine("name of student {0} is: " + studenst[i].name, i);
        Console.WriteLine("family name of student {0} is: " + students[i].familyName, i);
        Console.WriteLine("age of student {0} is: " + students[i].age, i);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {   public class Student
{
public string id;
 public string name;
 public string familyName;
 public string age;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          List<Student> studentList=new List<Student>();
          do
          {
              // ask user if he wants to add more students
              Console.WriteLine("do you want to add more? if no please write -No- to terminate and see what you have entered. If yes, please enter -Yes-");
              string read = Console.ReadLine(); 
              if (read == "No")
              {
                  /* You can also access List like this
                   * 
                   * foreach(Student s in studentList)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("id of student {0} is: "  s.id);
                    .
                    .
                    .
                  }*/
                  for (int i = 1; i < studentList.Count(); i++)
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("id of student {1} is{0}: ", studentList[i].id);
                      Console.WriteLine("name of student {1} is{0}: ", studentList[i].name, i);
                      Console.WriteLine("family name of student {1} is{0}: ", studentList[i].familyName, i);
                      Console.WriteLine("age of student {1} is: {0}", studentList[i].age, i);
                  }
                  break;
              }
              else {
                  Student s = new Student();
                  //Ask for id
                  s.id = Console.ReadLine();                   
                 //  And same for othre deatil 
                  studentList.Add(s);                   
              }
          } while (true);
    }
}
}
```